# How to make on div on top of another with table-cell?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, tablecell

I'm trying to make two divs to be one on top of another, like this:

[image: the problem]

### The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eppwb0e1/):

```
<!-- CSS -->
.table {
  display:table;
}
.div1 {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.div2 {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
<!-- /CSS -->
<div class="table">
  <div class="div1">
    Top
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    Bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a wrapper element with display: table-row; in each table-cell element you want to isolate. This will stack the cells in different rows, one on top of the other.

And don't use tables for your layout ... here's why: [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Comment: Thank you, table-row was the answer! I feel stupid for forgetting about this lol. I'll take a look at the link you recommended, thanks again.

Comment: You should not use tables if you are just dealing with basic elements. Try to only use tables for charts/boxes if needed.

Answer (score 1):

when I did the fiddle.... I came up with this (no css)

```
<div>
    <div align='center'>
        <div>
            Socrates (this should be on top of his head)
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.mrdowling.com/images/701socrates.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. Tables are not the way to go nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for the try, I knew I could do it this way, but in my specific case it doesn't work because I need the div to be aligned vertically as well, not just horizontally. It was my mistake, when I created the Fiddle I did not specify this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Html:**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="align-middle">
        Socrates (this should be on top of his head)    
        <img src="http://www.mrdowling.com/images/701socrates.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.align-middle {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but I need the image to be aligned to the bottom of the div class table.